# Binomial coefficients for negative entries

Tags: combinatorics, documentation

Mathematica evaluates the binomial coefficient   $\binom{-1}{-1}$ to 1. That agrees with an application I have in mind. However many books, such as Concrete Mathematics, [e.g. see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369624/suming-combinations-in-binomial-theorem/2369767#2369767),  define $\binom{t}{b} =0 $ for $b<0$. The Mathematica documentation for binomial says, rather briefly, that the value is calculated as the limit of the definition of factorial via Gamma function, i.e 
as ``a suitable limits of''
$\binom{t}{b}=\Gamma(t+1)/\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma(t-b+1)$.

I was wondering if anyone can shed some light on this issue. As there are two variables involved, $(t,b)$, then taking a limit does not seem well-defined.

Edit:

1- An explanation is given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45656/binomial-1-1?rq=1)

2- There is a [related paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.3689.pdf)

I believe Mathematica documentation needs some additional explanation in this regard.